# Как в случае отсутствия файла на сервере перенаправить запрос на PHP

Tags: nginx

К примеру у меня есть URL /images/articles/200x200/1.jpg
Я хочу, чтобы nginx отдавал эту картинку и все картинки из папки images статикой, а в случае отсутствия файла на сервере, обрабатывал бы этот же URL через php

Думаю вот что-то такое, но нужно доделывать наверное:

```
location /images {

    location ~ ^/images/uploads/ {
        error_page 404 .... $uri @fallback;
    }

}
```

Comment: например, так: `location /images {try_files $uri /через.php;}`

Comment: Тогда же все файлы будут через php пробрасываться

Comment: а вы проверьте, указав несуществующий `/через.php`

Comment: Я не понял что вы хотели выразить вложенным `location`?